# Bind local data to kendo grid and make it sortable

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am trying to setup kendo mvc ui grid using local data and make it sortable as in this demo [Binding to local data](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/local-data-binding).
However grid doesn't show data and if I hook up the onDataBound event, data inside there is undefined.
If I comment out DataSource setup on view, data gets populated at first, but disappears after sorting performed on any column.
I am using Kendo UI version: "2013.3.1119", asp.net mvc 4.
Please advice. 
Thanks.

## view

```
@model TestViewModel
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.TestList)
    .Name("grid2")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound( p => p.Id ).Title( "ID" );
        columns.Bound( p => p.Name ).Title("Product Name");
    })
    .Pageable()
    .Sortable()
    .Scrollable(scr=>scr.Height(430)) 
    .Filterable()    
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource        
        .Ajax()
        .PageSize(20)
        .ServerOperation(false))
)
```

## controller and model

```
    public class TestController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Test/
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var mdl = new TestViewModel();
        mdl.TestList = Test().ToList();

        return View(mdl);
    }

    public IEnumerable<TestMe> Test()
    {
        var lst = new List<TestMe>();
        for( int i = 0; i < 5; i++ )
        {
            lst.Add( new TestMe
            {
                Id = i,
                Name = i.ToString(),
            } );
        }
        return lst;
    }
}

public class TestViewModel
{
    public List<TestMe> TestList { get; set; }

    public TestViewModel()
    {
        TestList = new List<TestMe>();
    }
}

public class TestMe
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You can use `$('#grid2').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.data()` to get and set data in the dataSource of your Grid.  Use this JQuery to check if you still have data. You can also use `dataSource._sort ` and `dataSource._filter` to check the current sorted and filtered state of your grid.

Comment: Thanks! That's certainly possible, when I tested grid setup using javascript notation it worked properly. But it would be much better for my needs if I will solution for given code sample. Will issue official ticket to telerik support.

Comment: Just as a note. The MVC binding merely resolves into a JQuery script tag that gets ran when the page loads. There must be a difference between the way you have the Jquery and Razor one set up.

Comment: newer version of kendo ui solves this issue!